# QTimer не работает, не меняется угол наклона линии

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

хотел написать программу, которая будет работать, как простой радар, за основу взял видео, где делают аналоговые часы, но в моей программе совершенно не работает поворот линии по таймеру. Пробовал в SLOT менять методы, использовал currentTime, но ничего не помогло. И если можно, задам еще один вопрос, при ручном изменение угла поворота линии, почему-то смещаются ее начальные значения, есть ли способ это как-то исправить? В QT я совсем новичок.

#### mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTimer>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override;


};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

#### mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(1000);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(this);

    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    painter.translate(QPoint(width()/2,height()/2));
    int R = 1.6*qMin(width()/2,height()/2);
    painter.drawEllipse(-235,-270,R,R); //рисование большого круга
    painter.drawEllipse(-180,-215,R/1.3,R/1.3); //рисование среднего круга
    painter.drawEllipse(-130,-160,R/1.8,R/1.8); //рисование маленького круга

    painter.drawLine(0,-290,0,230); //рисование вертикальной линии
    painter.drawLine(-250,-20,260,-20);//рисование горизонтальной линии
    painter.setPen(Qt::green);
    painter.rotate(6.0*60);
    painter.drawLine(0,-20,0,-270); //рисование линии, которая должна поворачиваться
    painter.end();
}
```

Comment: QMainWindow::update() - это метод, но не слот. Вам нужно создать свой слот, и в нем вызвать this->update(), передав ему область для перерисовки. Используйте connect() с указателями на функции, тогда такие ошибки будут выявляться на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Я сделал в mainwindow.h слот 
public slots:
    void function();
Дальше сделал рефакторинг, чтобы эта функция появилась в mainwindow.cpp. И вот дальше я  к сожалению не очень понимаю, что нужно написать в самой функции, которую мы вставим в SLOT. Не могли бы вы снова мне помочь?

Comment: В слоте нужно вызвать метод this->update(this->rect()); тогда, каждый раз, будет вызываться событие paintEvent(). Только учтите, что в painEvent вы все перерисовываете заново, следовательно угол поворота вам нужно сохранять вне функции.

Comment: Я похоже опять делаю что-то нет так, потому что линия все равно не меняет угол наклона.

public slots:
     void func();




void MainWindow::func()
{
        this->update(this->rect());
}

Answer (score 0):

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    
    public:
        MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();
    
    private slots:
        void onTimeout();
    
    private:
        int angle;
    
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override;
    };
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    angle = 0;
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::onTimeout);
    timer->start(1000);    
}


void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(this);

    painter.translate(QPoint(width()/2,height()/2));

    angle = (angle >= 0 && angle <= 350) ? angle+10 : 0;

    painter.drawLine(0,-290,0,230); //рисование вертикальной линии
    painter.drawLine(-250,0,260,0);//рисование горизонтальной линии
    painter.setPen(Qt::green);
    painter.rotate(angle);
    painter.drawLine(0,0,0,-270); //рисование линии, которая должна поворачиваться
    painter.end();

}

void MainWindow::onTimeout()
{
    this->update(this->rect());
}
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!!!